# why do ranges algorithms take rvalue reference as argument

Tags: c++, reference, c++20, std-ranges

if I take for example the ranges::fill algorithm:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fill

the signature is:

```
template< class T, ranges::output_range<const T&> R >
constexpr ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<R> fill( R&& r, const T& value );
```

And an example use:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    namespace ranges = std::ranges;
    ranges::fill(v, 10);
}
```

Why does ranges::fill take a rvalue reference as argument ( R&& r) ?
I would have expected it to take a lvalue reference ( R& r) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `R` is a template parameter, `R&&` is not an *rvalue reference*, it is a [*forwarding/universal reference*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

> #### Forwarding references
>
> Forwarding references are a special kind of references that preserve
> the value category of a function argument, making it possible to
> forward it by means of std::forward. Forwarding references are either:
>
> 1. function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue
>    reference to cv-unqualified type template parameter of that same
>    function template:
>
>    ```
>    template<class T>
>    int f(T&& x) {                    // x is a forwarding reference
>        return g(std::forward<T>(x)); // and so can be forwarded
>    }
>
>    int main() {
>        int i;
>        f(i); // argument is lvalue, calls f<int&>(int&), std::forward<int&>(x) is lvalue
>        f(0); // argument is rvalue, calls f<int>(int&&), std::forward<int>(x) is rvalue
>    }
>
>    template<class T>
>    int g(const T&& x); // x is not a forwarding reference: const T is not cv-unqualified
>
>    template<class T> struct A {
>        template<class U>
>        A(T&& x, U&& y, int* p); // x is not a forwarding reference: T is not a
>                                 // type template parameter of the constructor,
>                                 // but y is a forwarding reference
>    };
>    ```
> 2. `auto&&` except when deduced from a brace-enclosed initializer list:
>
>    ```
>    auto&& vec = foo();       // foo() may be lvalue or rvalue, vec is a forwarding reference
>    auto i = std::begin(vec); // works either way
>    (*i)++;                   // works either way
>    g(std::forward<decltype(vec)>(vec)); // forwards, preserving value category
>
>    for (auto&& x: f()) {
>      // x is a forwarding reference; this is the safest way to use range for loops
>    }
>
>    auto&& z = {1, 2, 3}; // *not* a forwarding reference (special case for initializer lists)
>    ```

Comment: Sadly, it got way less readable than previously, due to lack of `typename` or `class` in OP's particular case. Now the template argument can be anything really...

Comment: @alagner I'm personally still yet to decide if things are harder to read due to more implicit/brief mechanisms, or just less familiar - I'm leaning towards the latter myself (concepts, removing need for typename when non-ambiguous and so on).

Comment: @drfib maybe I should have written "at this stage". No strong opinions here, either. For sure I'm used to the pre-20 form.